# How to edit the file located in C:\program files using C# in windows 7?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7

We are C# winform application.I want to modify the content of the xml file located in "c:\program files\filezilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml".It is working fine with **Windows XP**.

When i accessing the file in **Windows 7** it throws UnauthroziedAccessException and program will be terminated with showing this message `"Access to path 'c:\program files\filezilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml' is denied"`.

Comment: Did you actually check that the user that runs the WinForms application can edit the file by hand?

Comment: As above, the program will run with the logged in users permissions, so if this user can't access the file then you'll get this. There could also be a file lock going on

Comment: @Marcin Hoppe : Sorry.Did not understand your question

Comment: You say that you are running your app with elevated rights. If so then is it possible that the FileZilla server is running and has locked the file so that other processes cannot modify it?

Comment: If it's a distributable application you'll have to dig into obtaining elevated permissions [UAC detailed with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware)

If its a local application, start Visual Studio as Admin or run the application as Administrator.

Comment: @PedroFerreira : It is local application.But I already launched application with administration prvileges.But still i get the exception...

Comment: Try turn off UAC and check if you can run.
If you can't that means the file is locked and you won't have acess without terminating the process that is locking it.

Answer (score 0):

You should launch the application with the administration privileges.

Comment: I already launched application with administration prvileges.But still i get the exception...

Comment: You may want to check which process is locking the file (if any) using the free [SysInternals' handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) tool. Use it as follows: `handle "FileZilla Server.xml"`. As noted by others, the file may be perhaps locked by something else (including FileZilla itself).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the file to a destination where you have write access, edit it, and then  copy the file back to c:\program files with "overwrite" parameter set to true.

```
File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);
```